# Is there a way to launch persistent cmd windows through SSH?

Tags: windows, ssh, cmd.exe, persistent

I want to ssh into a remote Windows box, and launch a .cmd file - the caveat being that the command window has to stay open for the launched application to remain accessible. Is this possible?

Comment: how are you doing SSH to a cmd prompt? Have you tried cmd /k blah.cmd ?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to launch a cmd as far as you have an ssh connection. The ssh session is your `cmd`. One option is to install Cygwin openssh server.